# Unicode characters not showing after using 'str_extract_all' function (stringr) in Rstudio

Tags: r, utf-8, tidyverse, stringr, tidytext

I am trying to extract a series of words from a series of .txt documents with the 'str_extract_all' stringr function. Everything works well except that the results I get do not show Unicode characters (which are fine in the UTF-8 texts where the information is extracted from). Does anybody know why this is happening?

---

[I am using RStudio on Windows 10.1]

I have converted my corpus of 5 .txt documents (novels) to a data frame through the following command:

```
tbl <- list.files(pattern = "*.txt") %>% 
    map_chr(~ read_file(.)) %>% 
    data_frame(text = .)
```

Unicode characters look fine on 'tbl', but when I run the str_extract_all function, they disappear. Here is my code:

```
uppercase <- sapply(str_extract_all(tbl, '(?<!^|\\.\\s|\\?\\s|\\!\\s)[A-Z][a-z]+'), paste)
```

This is the result I get:

```
[1,] "For"       
[2,] "Ant"       
[3,] "Pati"
```

etc.

When it should read:

```
[1,] "For"       
[2,] "Antón"       
[3,] "Patiño"
```

etc.

Is this a stringr bug, or has anybody experienced anything similar before? Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the character class `[A-z]` (and its subsets `[A-Z]`, `[a-z]`) does not work for special characters such as `ñ` and `ó`. `[[:alpha:]]`(alphabetic characters) on the other hand seems to work.

```
stringr::str_extract_all(c("Antón", "Patiño"), '[A-z]+')
```

returns:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Ant" "n"  

[[2]]
[1] "Pati" "o"
```

whereas

```
stringr::str_extract_all(c("Antón", "Patiño"), '[[:alpha:]]+')
```

returns the desired outcome:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Antón"

[[2]]
[1] "Patiño"
```

Comment: Many thanks for this JdeMello, it hadn't even occurred to me that the Regex could be the problem. It does indeed work with the [[:alpha:]] version!